# Parse a String (of array of strings) in JSON to an array of Strings in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

Does Swift provide a way to convert a **raw** String like this

```
"[\"John\",\"Anna\",\"Tom\"]"
```

to an Array of strings (`[String]`)?

I've looked for a way to do it over StackOverflow, but in that specific way, I could not find an answer :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Swift 4 and later, use `JSONDecoder`:

```
let rawString = "[\"John\",\"Anna\",\"Tom\"]"
let jsonData = rawString.data(using: .utf8)!
let strings = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: jsonData)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Code Different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51991420/1033581) is probably a recommended way to do it nowadays (Swift 4+).

For reference, here is a classic way to do the same, compatible with older Swift versions:

```
let rawString = "[\"John\",\"Anna\",\"Tom\"]"
let jsonData = rawString.data(using: .utf8)!
let strings = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])) as? [String] ?? []
```

According to Itai Ferber, [*`JSONDecoder` uses `JSONSerialization` under the hood*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102094/jsonserialization-jsonobject-performance-in-swift/45105790#comment77183040_45105790), so it should do pretty much the same as Code Different answer.